# How to sort a multidimensional list to alphabetical order based on its first row letters in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

How do I sort a multidimensional list to alphabetical order based on its first row of data without using numpy nor other modules

For example I have a list:

```
[['M', 'A', 'R', 'K']
[1,    3,   5,    4]
[2,    6,   7,    8]]
```

I want it to be like:

```
[['A', 'K', 'M', 'R']
[3,    4,   1,    5]
[6,    8,   2,    7]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything? Include what you tried

Comment: I have tried using numy like the example below, but I haven't found a solution without using one.

Comment: That should be a part of your question like you want without using "nummy"? That wil give the clear idea what you want?Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there should be a better way; anyway, this would do the trick:

```
>>> l = [['M', 'A', 'R', 'K'], [1, 3, 5, 4], [2, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> sorted_l = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(*l))))
>>> print(list(sorted_l))
[['A', 'K', 'M', 'R'], [3, 4, 1, 5], [6, 8, 2, 7]]
```

Edit:

1. `zip(*l)` gives you an iterator (in Python 3), if you do `[i for i in zip(*l)]`, you'll find it looks like `[('M', 1, 2), ('A', 3, 6), ('R', 5, 7), ('K', 4, 8)]`
2. `sorted(zip(*l))` sorts the list above (becomes `[('A', 3, 6), ('K', 4, 8), ('M', 1, 2), ('R', 5, 7)]` under the hood), I didn't specify the key, so it compares the elements directly
3. then, you zip again, and you get an iterator of what you wants (elements in `l` are `('A', 'K', 'M', 'R'), (3, 4, 1, 5), (6, 8, 2, 7)` if you print them out); however, you have to do `map()` so you can get `<class 'list'>` instead of `<class 'tuple'>`
4. finally, `map()` also returns an iterator in Python3, to get a list, you simply use `list([iterable])` to construct the final list.

Documentations: [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), and [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Answer (score 2):

Once you know the new "order" (or mapping) of the sorted indexes, you should be able to use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to basically walk all the rows and get the items in the order that you just found.

In your case, you have `['M', 'A', 'R', 'K']`. In order to get those letters sorted, you should first get index `1`, then index `3`, then index `0` and finally index `2`: `(A K M R)`. Once you find that mapping, you can just call `itemgetter` to get you the items on each row in that order.

```
import operator
a=[
    ['M', 'A', 'R', 'K'],
    [1,    3,   5,    4],
    [2,    6,   7,    8],
]
sorted_first = sorted(a[0])
sorted_indexes = [a[0].index(letter) for letter in sorted_first]
print "Mapping: %s" % sorted_indexes
new_sorted = [operator.itemgetter(* sorted_indexes)(line) for line in a]
print new_sorted
```

Which ouputs:

```
Mapping: [1, 3, 0, 2]
[('A', 'K', 'M', 'R'),
 (3, 4, 1, 5),
 (6, 8, 2, 7)]
```

### EDIT:

[rpatisso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2726734/rpattiso) made me see (in comments to this answer) that there's more effective way to calculate the `sorted_indexes` variable than using [list.index](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm) which is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*:

```
sorted_indexes = sorted(range(len(a[0])), key=lambda i: a[0][i])
```

Comment: searching for the location in the list of every element for `sorted_indexes` is not very efficient O(n^2).

Comment: The 4 item list is only an example.

Comment: How do you know? and, according to you, what would be a more efficient way then?

Comment: The OP said "For example" and `sorted_indices = sorted(range(len(a[0])), key=lambda i: a[0][i])` would be O(nlog n), like the accepted answer.

Comment: Dang! You're right. I tried to start doing it that way, gave me some errors... went with `index`.

Comment: I've edited the question to add your remarks. If you mind, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with numpy.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([['M', 'A', 'R', 'K'],
... [1,    3,   5,    4],
... [2,    6,   7,    8]], dtype=object)
>>> a[:,np.argsort(a[0])]
array([['A', 'K', 'M', 'R'],
       [3, 4, 1, 5],
       [6, 8, 2, 7]], dtype=object)
```

Without numpy:

```
>>> map(list,zip(*sorted(zip(*a))))
[['A', 'K', 'M', 'R'], [3, 4, 1, 5], [6, 8, 2, 7]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using numpy?